# Issues scheduling alarms when getting the time to set the AlarmManger for using a TimePicker because of AM/PM

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sms, alarmmanager

I'm programming an app that has a feature that the user can use to set an alarm for an SMS message to be send to someone. The problem I am having is say the user sets the Alarm-Manager to go off at 9:00 A.M. and it is currently 10:00 P.M. then the alarm immediately goes off. It doesn't recognize the fact that the alarm should be set for the next day.

Here is the code for setting up the AlarmManager:

```
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(MainMenu.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intentAlarm.putExtra("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
intentAlarm.putExtra("message", message);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainMenu.this, 1, intentAlarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
```

Other than the AM/PM issue, the AlarmManager works well. I just don't know where to go from here and all of the documentation I am looking at just doesn't help.

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat` with `24 Hours`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 10); // use hour of day for am pm issue
    cal1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    cal1.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        if (now.after(cal1))
            cal1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
// this code snippet add one day if the current time passed away 
//else use cal1.set(year, month, day); for exact day
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void SetAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    // set alarm after 12 hours
    long after = System.currentTimeMillis() + 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, after, pi);
}
```